# Batch Script to run NET USE Command five times and continue or break depend on error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a DOS script where I want to run the NET USE command and if the ERRORLEVEL returns 0 then it will continue to next command or line, else it will wait for 5 second and then attempt to do NET USE again. It will make 5 attempts at NET USE and if the return code 1 then again (after 5 times the return code doesn't come 0 then it will exit).

```
NET USE L: \\%cdqm_at_webserver_1%\%cdqm_at_web_server_drive%$\CMBUILDS %cxda_user_password% /USER:cxda\%cxda_user_name%
SET A=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
timeout 5 >NUL
```

I am not sure how could I do these attempt?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I made this script.Could some check and let me know if need to add anyting?

```
SET COUNT=0
:MyLoop
IF “%COUNT%” == “5” GOTO EndLoop
NET USE L: \\%cdqm_at_webserver_1%\%cdqm_at_web_server_drive%$\CMBUILDS %cxda_user_password% /USER:cxda\%cxda_user_name%
SET A=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
Timeout 5>NUL
SET /A COUNT+=1
GOTO MyLoop
) ELSE (
ECHO “DRIVE HAS MAPPED SUCCESSFULLY”
)
:EndLoop
```